# Communicating between UITableViewCells in a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uibutton, communication, uitableview

I know this is a common question topic.  However I haven't found an answer after extensive searching so I'm asking it here.

I have a **UITableViewController** where each row is an instance of a **UITableViewCell** subclass.  Each UITableViewCell subclass has a **UIButton**.  Initially all UIButtons have the same image (just a blue circle).  Tapping a button causes only that button's image to change (say to a red circle).  This part is easy:  just handle the tap inside the UITableViewCell subclass and toggle the image.

Here's the challenging part:  when I tap another blue button I want the button that's currently red (if any) to toggle it's image back to blue.  **How can I tell this button to toggle it's image?**

**Where do I keep track of the button that's currently red?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` method in your UITableViewCell subclass. When the cell is selected, make the UIButton image red; otherwise, set the UIButton image to blue. This method is called whenever a new cell is selected, so there will always be only one red-button cell.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(selected)
    {
        [myButton setImage:RED_IMAGE forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //or however else you want to change your button's image
    }else
    {
        [myButton setImage:BLUE_IMAGE forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't quite work.  Recall I'm tapping the buttons in each UITableViewCell subclass (not the UITableViewCell itself).

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, why are you using buttons?

Comment: No problem :-)  The UITableViewCell subclass has a button due to the app design.  So tapping a cell does one thing while tapping the button in a cell does something else.

Comment: Okay, then you could implement a static class that keeps a pointer to the currently selected button. When a new button is pressed, tell the old button (the one held by the static class) to change its image. Once that is done, set the pointer in the static class to the new currently selected button.